# Lucene Analyzer for Indexing and Searching

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a field that I am indexing with Lucene like so:

```
@Field(name="hungerState", index=Index.TOKENIZED, store=Store.YES)
public HungerState getHungerState() {
```

The possible values of this field are `HUNGRY, SLIGHTLY_HUNGRY, and NOT_HUNGRY`

When these values are indexed using the `StandardAnalyzer`, the terms end up as `hungry, slightly` since it tokenizes on punctuation and ignores the "not".

If I change the index to `index=Index.UN_TOKENIZED`, the indexed terms are `HUNGRY, SLIGHTLY_HUNGRY, and NOT_HUNGRY`, as expected.

My search API has 1 "search" method that constructs the `Query` like so:

```
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, getSearchFields(), new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30));
parser.setDefaultOperater(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
Query query = parser.parse(searchTerms);
```

This handles searches where searchTerms = "foo", which searches all fields returned by `getSearchFields()` on "foo", and also where searchTerms specifies fields and values to search (ie "hungerState:HUNGRY")

**My problem is with the latter scenario**. Since the query parser is using a StandardAnalyzer, searches for `hungerState:SLIGHTLY_HUNGRY` get parsed into `hungerState:"slightly hungry"` and searches for `hungerState=NOT_HUNGRY` get parsed into `hungerState=hungry`.

When the field is indexed using the StandardAnalyzer, I get unexpected results (searches for HUNGRY and NOT_HUNGRY return results for all 3 values). When the field is indexed as UN_TOKENIZED, I don't get any results since the query parser tokenizes the search string and makes it lowercase.

I've even tried specifying an Analyzer for indexing like `KeywordAnalyzer`, but it pretty much has no effect since the entire search string is analyzed with `StandardAnalyzer` every time.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a standard analyzer for your query parser, so yes your query will be analyzed with a standard analyzer. Just switch to using a keyword analyzer:

```
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, getSearchFields(), 
          new KeywordAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30));
```

You may want to use a [PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html) if your other fields aren't keywords.

Comment: The PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper is exactly what I need, since the StandardAnalyzer is fine for all of my other fields.